# What would happen if you tried to use oil as fuel in a fusion reactor?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atoms, hydrogen, fusion

At first, this question seemed silly, but there might be some sense to it.  OpenAI's GPT algorithm suggested to me that using oil in fusion technology could be a breakthrough.  I thought about it for a bit, and my first thought is that the oil might combust, but the chemical combustion energy is small in comparison to the energy of nuclear fusion, so it probably wouldn't do much good.  However, it does have hydrogen (it is a hydrocarbon).

Now, I wonder if the molecules of the oil would hold the hydrogen in place, so freely roaming atoms of hydrogen might more readily fuse to it during high heat?  My thought is no, at least not for long, because the extreme temperatures of fusion would break the molecules into atoms.  I wonder though if the atoms being close together (as molecules of hydrogen in the oil) might improve the rate of fusion, even though there are other elements mixed in?  What are your thoughts, do you think oil would have any advantages over using hydrogen (particularly deuterium) in a fusion reactor?

*Edit:*
Another angle I haven't considered is the newly discovered C-N-O fusion cycle which is a catalyst for fusing hydrogen into helium.  I wonder if that makes using oil more feasible?
https://youtu.be/jPE2IWnpCgs

Comment: You've kind of answered your own question: chemical energies are extremely feeble compared to nuclear energies. BTW, plain hydrogen is a terrible fuel for a fusion reactor, unless you have stellar quantities on hand, and a lot of time.

Comment: Newly discovered? Carl Friedrich von Weizsäcker and Hans Bethe wrote about the CNO cycle in the late 1930's, over 80 years ago. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNO_cycle What's new is the experimental detection of the neutrinos produced by the CNO cycle in the Sun. The Sun's core isn't hot enough to do much CNO fusion. As Wikipedia says, only 1.7% of $\mathrm{{}^4He}$ nuclei produced in the Sun are born in the CNO cycle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At energies high enough to smash hydrogens together hard enough to make them fuse, the oil molecules that contain them have long since been torn to pieces. This means the scheme holds no advantage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will see if anyone else has any thoughts, and if not, will probably accept this as the answer!  In the case where lasers are used to rapidly heat the fusing material in a rapid pulse, do you think the atoms starting close together (in the molecules of oil) would offer any advantage?

Comment: @Jonathan No, because when you heat oil to a million degrees, the atoms tend to become very far apart, unless you also supply a lot of pressure. Under those conditions, it doesn't really matter what your starting material is, because it's been blasted into fully ionised atoms. BTW, in the [Sun's core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_core) the plasma density is around 150 g/cm³ with a temperature around 15 million kelvin. But even under those conditions, it takes around 1 billion years (on average) for a hydrogen atom to succeed in becoming part of a helium atom.